# Find the minimum iterations in a loop - BigQuery

Tags: sql, loops, google-bigquery, iteration

I'm trying to establish a code in BigQuery SQL to find the minimum iterations needed to cover all items.

In details, say I have a table with 3 columns: Site, Router, PC.
Each site has multiple routers that are connected to different PCs.
I want to find the minimum routers needed in each site that covers ALL the PCs in the site.
For example: In site X I have 5 different routers connected to 9 PCs, but I can keep only 3 routers that will give a full coverage of the PCs. Routers AAA, BBB, DDD can see all 9 PCs. I can drop routers CCC and EEE and I still have a full coverage for all the PCs.

Raw data:

[image]

```
with pop as (
select 'X' as site,'AAA' as router, 1 as pc union all
select 'X' as site,'AAA' as router, 2 as pc union all
select 'X' as site,'AAA' as router, 3 as pc union all
select 'X' as site,'AAA' as router, 4 as pc union all
select 'X' as site,'AAA' as router, 5 as pc union all
select 'X' as site,'BBB' as router, 4 as pc union all
select 'X' as site,'BBB' as router, 6 as pc union all
select 'X' as site,'BBB' as router, 7 as pc union all
select 'X' as site,'CCC' as router, 2 as pc union all
select 'X' as site,'CCC' as router, 4 as pc union all
select 'X' as site,'CCC' as router, 7 as pc union all
select 'X' as site,'DDD' as router, 1 as pc union all
select 'X' as site,'DDD' as router, 8 as pc union all
select 'X' as site,'DDD' as router, 9 as pc union all
select 'X' as site,'EEE' as router, 5 as pc union all
select 'X' as site,'EEE' as router, 6 as pc union all
select 'Y' as site,'FFF' as router, 1 as pc union all
select 'Y' as site,'GGG' as router, 2 as pc union all
select 'Y' as site,'HHH' as router, 1 as pc union all
select 'Y' as site,'HHH' as router, 2 as pc union all
select 'Y' as site,'HHH' as router, 3 as pc 
)

select *
from pop
```

Expected outcome:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "*... minimum routers needed in each site that covers ALL the PCs ...*" - Update your post with the definition of "router covering a pc".

Comment: and please provide data as text, not graphics; don't expect people to type all that.

Comment: Seems only sure way (at least to me) is to, for each site, 1, check each route to see if any can cover all PCs. if not, 2. check each combination of two routes to see if any two can cover all PCs. if not, 3. check each combination of three routes to see if any three can cover all PCs, and so on so forth until finding a combination having all PCs covered.

Comment: I can post a SQL Server version, but you will need to adapt it to your rdbms' bitwise AND syntax, if you wish (I don't have access to a biqquery environment

Comment: It will be much appreciated. Tnx @tinazmu

Answer (score 1):

We can use a 'number table' to enumerate all combinations (representing the routers as 1 bits in an integer value and using the bitwise AND function):

```
with MyTbl as (
       select *
       from (
       values       
        ('X','AAA',1)       ,('X','AAA',2)       ,('X','AAA',3)       ,('X','AAA',4)       ,('X','AAA',5)       ,('X','BBB',4)
       ,('X','BBB',6)       ,('X','BBB',7)       ,('X','CCC',2)       ,('X','CCC',4)       ,('X','CCC',7)       ,('X','DDD',1)
       ,('X','DDD',8)       ,('X','DDD',9)       ,('X','EEE',5)       ,('X','EEE',6)       ,('X','FFF',1)       ,('Y','GGG',2)
       ,('Y','HHH',1)       ,('Y','HHH',2)       ,('Y','HHH',3)
       ) T (Site, Router, PC)
),
Nos as (
    -- Up to 8 routers per site are supported
    select T0.N+T1.N*2+T2.N*4+T3.N*8+T4.N*16+T5.N*32+T6.N*64+T7.N*128 as Combtn
       from
             (values (0),(1)) T0(N), (values (0),(1)) T1(N), (values (0),(1)) T2(N), (values (0),(1)) T3(N),
             (values (0),(1)) T4(N), (values (0),(1)) T5(N), (values (0),(1)) T6(N), (values (0),(1)) T7(N)
),
Routers as (
       select Site
              , Router
              , power(2, row_number()  over (partition by Site order by Router)) as RouterSeqBM
       from (select distinct Site, Router from MyTbl) S1
),
RouterCombos as (
       select R.Site, N.Combtn, R.Router
       from Nos N
            inner join Routers R
            on R.RouterSeqBM & N.Combtn <> 0 --< Adjust this & 
)
select RC.Site, RC.Router
from
(
    select *
    from (
        -- Choose the coombination with the least no of routers
            select Seqd.*
                , row_number() 
                        over (partition by Site 
                            order By NumRouters) as NumRouterSeq
            from (
                -- count routers for each site covering all PCs
                    select Site, Combtn, count(*) as NumRouters
                    from RouterCombos RC
                    where not exists  -- Make sure that all PCs are covered
                                (select 1
                                from MyTbl MT
                                where MT.Site=RC.Site
                                and MT.PC not in 
                                   (select distinct PC
                                    from
                                        RouterCombos RC2
                                        inner join MyTbl MT2
                                        on MT2.Site=RC2.Site
                                        and MT2.Router=RC2.Router
                                    where RC2.Combtn=RC.Combtn
                                    and RC2.Site=RC.Site))
                    group by Site, Combtn
                    ) Seqd
            ) Seqd1
       where Seqd1.NumRouterSeq=1
) BestRouterCombs
  inner join
  RouterCombos RC
  on RC.Site=BestRouterCombs.Site
  and RC.Combtn=BestRouterCombs.Combtn
```

This works in SQLServer, you would need to adjust it for your environment.